# How to pull or push a project using TortoiseHg to GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, mercurial, tortoisehg

Recently, I have learned about version control systems (like- Git & Mercurial) and fell in love for them. I have checked TortoiseHg, TortoiseGit, EGit, Git-Bash, Git-Gui and SourceTree. I also have signed up in GitHub and Bitbucket; and learned about- how open-source & commercial projects are hosted there.

Now, I wish to upload my projects online too. But the problem is- I want to use **TortoiseHg** in my PC (cause, it is simply wonderful!), and keep my projects in **GitHub**. I have browsed on internet and came to know about converting Mercurial repository to Git, but I don't know, it seemed complex to me. Is there any easy way to do this?

Actually, I don't want to use 3rd party software; but if there is really no other way out, I am willing to try that option too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also fell into the same problem. And thanks to the TortoiseHg developers, they created a super simple extension for this (**hggit**). You will not even feel, that you are working with two different version control systems.

First, go to: **File > Settings > Extensions**, and check **hggit**-

[image]

Now, for pulling or pushing a project all you have to do is to put a `git+` prefix before the repository `url`-

[image]

That is all you have to do! Now clone, pull, push; you won't have to worry about any thing.

Comment: Do I have to install this extension?

Comment: You don't have to install anything. Just go to-  File > Settings > Extensions, you will find it. This extension comes automatically with TortoiseHg package.

Comment: Oh, I found it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I am able to push my project to github. But, why do I have to input my name and password **two times**?

Comment: I had to do that too, but don't know why :(

Comment: @Stupid and Minhas - you can migrate to `git+ssh://` + PageAnt (with some tricks) easy or add http-credentials to [`[auth]` section](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth) or repository's .hgrc

Comment: I had an error about `no module named selectors` whenever I clicked pull, but I was able to push and pull by dropping to the Windows command line (if you set the default url as above, `hg pull` is all you need).

Comment: is this still working? I tried today but it is not working with me.